# Bitlbee without password

Tags: passwords, irc, irssi

I have a local instance of bitlbee to which I connect from irssi on the same machine. Since everything is on `localhost`, I don't think it makes much sense for me to need to `identify (password)` every reconnect. Is it possible to skip password prompts? The documentation doesn't say anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to automatize sending the `identify (password)` in the IRC client.

For `irssi`, things might look like this in the `chatnets` entry:

```
localhost = {
  type = "IRC";
  autosendcmd = "/^msg -localhost &bitlbee identify PASSWORD";
  max_kicks = "1";
  max_msgs = "3";
  max_whois = "30";
};
```

Make sure that `localhost` entry key and `localhost` in the `/msg` match, otherwise the command won't work.

Alternatively you could also `/privmsg root` on the relevant network, but this will open a new window / tab which might be undesired.

Comment: Weechat equivalent: `/set irc.server.bitlbee.command /msg &bitlbee identify PASSWORD;` and `/save`.